# Why there is no post in for range ? Golang

Tags: go

I would like to increment a variable after each range loop. However it seems it's not possible using the standard (   `for init; condition; post { }` )  for syntax therefore I'm wondering why . Here is what I'm trying to do

```
    for item := range itemsList; page++ {

}
```

It seems the only way to do this is

```
        for item := range itemsList{

       page++
    }
```

which doesn't look as nice as the first one.

Comment: It is pretty useless to ask something which is a plain syntax error, the Go specification is very clear about it and you can never ever have found such code anywhere. It is like asking for C: "Why cannot i write `(if (gt a 5) foo bar)` it looks so much nicer to me than `if(a>5) foo(); else bar();`.

Comment: Reading the spec (which is neither long, nor hard to understand) should be your first step when you're not sure of something in the language.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm aware of the syntax so I was just wondering why the specs lack a post statement in the range clause.

Comment: @Volker for ``for i := range iList; page++ `` seems very similar to me with ``for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {``.  I didn't ask for C parens.

Comment: @Volker, you can) In Lisp... Golang's `for/range` is foreach loop (js: `for(var in o);`, php: `foreach($o as $v); java for(int i: list);`... No reason to add and parse excess clause here, absolutely. Just add your business logic(incrementing) to loop body.

Answer (score 8):

The [`for` statement specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) does mention that a [Range Clause](http://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause) stands alone.

```
ForStmt = "for" [ Condition | ForClause | RangeClause ] Block .
```

As opposed to a [Post Statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#PostStmt), which is part of:

```
ForClause = [ InitStmt ] ";" [ Condition ] ";" [ PostStmt ] .
```

That means a post statement is only valid in the context of an initialization and a condition, in order to potentially make that condition change (since it is executed after each execution of the block, and *only if the block was executed*).

There is no such need (making a condition stops a loop) in a Range clause, where the fact that the loop has been done over all the elements of a range (of an array, slice, string, map, or channel permitting receive operations) is enough for the loop to stops.

A range expression is evaluated once before beginning the loop (or at least its length is). There is no need to change anything after each execution of the block.

So trying to add a post statement to a range loop would generate a compilation  error like:

```
expected '{', found ';'
```